# Can't put light effect on text in GIMP

Tags: gimp, text

I've been searching for a solution for two hours now, but I can't find any. My logo is almost done, but I would like to apply some lighting on my picture with the blend tool, and I can't get it on the text. The Sala and Plast parts were originally texts, and I merged it with the border layer. Now if I put the light on it only apllies to the border as you can see on the picture below (I changed the original white light to red to make it more visible)

Thank you

[image: questin_stackexchange]

Answer (score 1):

The `Overlay` mode equation is:

[image]

Where I (image) is the channel from your image and M (mask) is the whatever you put over it (layer or paint tool with said mode. In  your black text, `I=0` so all you can get is 0 (in other words, black always remains black in an overlay blend).

So, try other modes (hard light or grain merge)...  or change your black to some dark gray.

PS: I have nothing against blend modes in paint tools, but you normally get the same results with a transparent layer in said blend mode that you paint with a tool in `Normal` mode, and in that case you can easily change the layer mode to test things out.